# Unable to access object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Im trying to access an object property but nothing is turning up , i've tried to access it in different ways and the only thing that actually pulls back anything is when i call "list".

this is my code.

```
var newP = $("<p>")
var userDate = ("#userDate")
var bitcoinApiUrl = "https://crossorigin.me/https://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: bitcoinApiUrl,
            success: function(currency) {
                // parse currency
                currency = JSON.parse(currency);

                // loop through currency
                for(var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) {
                    console.log(currency[i]); //this is the object
                    //use dot notation to get object values
                    var volume = currency[i].volume,
                    latestTrade = currency[i].latest_trade,
                    bid = currency[i].bid,
                    high = currency[i].high,
                    currencyString = currency[i].currency;

                    // Create a string to log
                    var list = "Volume:"+volume+"\n"+"Latest Trade: "+latestTrade+"\n"+"Bid: "+bid+"\n"+"High: "+high+"\n"+"Currency: "+currencyString+"\n"+"\n"+"\n";
                    var currencyList = "Currency: "+currencyString+"\n"+"\n"+"\n";
                    // log the string
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $(".modalinfo").append(list.currency);
                        console.log(list["currency"]);

                    })
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have a ready handler inside a loop that is inside a ready handler?

Comment: it was a mistake , was that the problem ?@LeeTaylor

Comment: Can you post some HTML code?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to fix that mistake...

Comment: Try removing `$(document).ready()` wrapper surrounding `$(".modalinfo").append(list.currency);
                        console.log(list["currency"]);`

Comment: What the he** is `var userDate = ("#userDate")` ?

Comment: @Villainy - Please look at my answer and provide feedback on what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: okay I'm trying to take specific properties from the object and dynamically place them on the HTML @LeeTaylor

Comment: @Villainy Please see my answer which does what you ask.

Comment: How can I use the data attribute to filter out the USD, I want to only get lines that are using the United states dollar ? i would use date-currency right ? @LeeTaylor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works fine. Please explain what it is you're trying to do.

```js
var bitcoinApiUrl = "https://crossorigin.me/https://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json";
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: bitcoinApiUrl,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(currency) {
        // loop through currency
        for (var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) 
        {
          if(currency[i].currency == "USD")
          {
              var $tr = $("<tr />");
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].volume) );
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].latest_trade) );
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].bid) );
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].high) );
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].currency) );
                     
              $("#theTable tbody").append($tr);
          }
        }
      }
  });
```

```css
#theTable
{
border-collapse: collapse;  
}

#theTable td
{
border: solid 1px black;padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Volume</td><td>Latest</td><td>Bid</td><td>High</td><td>Currency</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var list = {volume: volume, latest_trade: latestTrade, bid: bid, high: high, currency: currencyString};
var currencyList = "Currency: "+currencyString+"\n"+"\n"+"\n";
$(".modalinfo").append(list.currency);
console.log(list.currency);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLdv24f1/3/)